# Python returns error on scapy.IP and scapy.TCP call

Tags: python, scapy

I am taking an online course on ethical hacking and i am trying to make a program in python that injects code into html, at this moment i am at the decoding HTML response stage.

```
def process_packet(packet):
    scapy_packet = scapy.IP(packet.get_payload())
    if scapy.Raw in scapy_packet and scapy.TCP in scapy_packet:
        if scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].dport == 80:
            print("[+] Request")
            modified_load = re.sub("Accept-Encoding:.*?//r//n", "", scapy_packet(scapy.Raw).load)
            new_packet = set_load(scapy_packet, modified_load)
            packet.setpayload(str(new_packet))
        elif scapy_packet[scapy.TCP].sport == 80:
            print("[+] Response")
            print(scapy_packet.show())

    packet.accept()
```

When I use the program in the terminal it waits with no errors until I open a tab in browser and go somewhere.
When I do that it gives me this error:

```
[+] Request
Exception ignored in: 'netfilterqueue.global_callback'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code_injector.py", line 25, in process_packet
    modified_load = re.sub("Accept-Encoding:.*?//r//n", "", scapy_packet(scapy.Raw).load)
TypeError: 'IP' object is not callable
```

I already used iptabels -I INPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num0 and iptabels -I OUTPUT -j NFQUEUE --queue-num0
to make it work in my local computer.
This is my first question, sorry for bad explaining.
These are my imports

```
import scapy.all as scapy
import netfilterqueue
import re
```

Comment: You mean `scapy_packet[scapy.Raw]`, not `scapy_packet(scapy.Raw)`. `packet(Raw)` attempts to call `packet` as a function. `packet[Raw]` attempts to get the `Raw` layer of `packet`. Voted to close as a typo.

Comment: Oh my god i cant belive i missed that. 
Thank you very much